# JavaScript function from class extension not recognized

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm playing around with classes ES6 and encountered behaviour with below code.

Error I'm getting is `bob.personName is not a function`.

Both class and it extension has `constructor` defined but still I can't get it working. I added comments under lines that I think might be the issue. Thanks for help!

```
class Person {
  constructor(canSpeak) {
    this.canSpeak = true;
  }
}

class Hello extends Person {
  constructor(name) {
  this.name = name;
  }

  personName() { //am I missing a parameter?
    if (this.canSpeak) {
      return `Name is: ${this.name}, can speak? ${this.canSpeak}`;
        }
    };
};

const bob = new Person('Bob'); //should I call Hello extension instead?
console.log(bob.personName());
```

Comment: `personName` is only a method of `Hello` instances, not `Person`.

Comment: Think of it this way. There is a car (Person) which has an optional sunroof (Hello), but you didn't go for that option, you bought the base model (Person), and now you're trying to open the sunroof

Comment: Yes, it fell through the cracks for me. I can't evoke function that is part of specific configuration from base level. I need to call it from where it resides. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the method exists on `Hello.prototype`, not on `Person.prototype`, you need the instance to be of a `Hello`.

You also can't reference `this` until calling `super` inside a subclass's constructor, so do that before assigning to `this.name`:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(canSpeak) {
    this.canSpeak = true;
  }
}

class Hello extends Person {
  constructor(name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
  }

  personName() { //am I missing a parameter?
    if (this.canSpeak) {
      return `Name is: ${this.name}, can speak? ${this.canSpeak}`;
    }
  };
};

const bob = new Hello('Bob'); //should I call Hello extension instead?
console.log(bob.personName());
```

Comment: Than you! I was thinking that `super` was what I missed.